# How do i calculate probability of 6 numbers?

Tags: probability

Hi all can anyone help me how to find probability of generating 6 different numbers from given 10 numbers?

Comment: How do you generate numbers from 10 numbers? Do you mean to draw a random number of those 10 and repeat that 6 times?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  Presumably you are selecting with replacement.  Clearly the first one you choose can't match anything.  What is the chance the second does not match the first?  Given that they don't match, what is the chance that the third doesn't match either of the first two?  Continue like this.  You need all of these to come true, so you ????? the numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming they're drawn uniformly, you can choose a set of 6 different numbers from 10 different numbers with order mattering $P(10,6)$ ways. The total number of 6-subsets which you can draw with replacement is $10^6$, so the probability of a set of 6 different numbers is $P(10,6)/10^6$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming uniform probability of drawing any of 10 numbers with possible replacement, we have two cases: either you recognize the order in which you draw, then you have:
$$ \frac{10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5}{10^6} = \frac{10!}{4! \cdot 10^6} $$
or you don't, in which case:
$$ \frac{10 \choose 6}{15 \choose 9} $$
The denominator here means the number of ways how to put 6 balls into 10 different holes, for example three balls in the second hole means that you have second number three times.